# PyCharm. Getting the Project Dir in the "Run/Debug Configuration" Window

Tags: python, environment-variables, pycharm

I want to share **PyCharm** run/debug configurations with my team. I need a way of configure run/debug configurations so they can work also in other computers.

Is there a dynamic way of getting the project's dir? Any ideas?

Perhaps a way to change say **"C:\PythonPlatform\Test\"** to something like **"${PROJECT_DIR}\Test"** in the **"Folders"** and **"Working directory"** fields? See the image:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are so called [*Macros*](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/macros-dialog.html) in PyCharm which include `$ProjectFileDir$` described as *The directory of the project file*. However it seems they can only be used in *External Tools* section and not in *Run/Debug Configurations*. However, there's very relevant issue titled [*Add support for macros in Run/Debug Configurations screen*](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-9399) raised in another JetBrains' product — *WebStorm*. There, we find information that the path to any file underneath project's directory is stored relatively to the project's directory meaning that if the project is placed somewhere else in the filesystem the file would still be found. In other words paths you see are presented as absolute paths but they are in fact relative to the project's directory. I must admit it's confusing to say the least.

I created issue [*Add support for macros in run/debug configurations*](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-11372) — feel free to vote on it.

Comment: Yes I knew about macros. So it seems there is no way of doing this? :( I will vote for the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @ElMarce There is a way — it's already **working**. Copy your project to different location (no matter if on the same computer or another) and see that all paths previously defined still work.

Comment: It does work now. You may update your answer. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-74031

Answer (score 2):

As a silly workaround for the very specific but common case of running a `main.py` script in the project root, you can select to run by "Mondule name" instead of the default "Script path":

[image]

This works because the "Add source roots to PYTHONPATH" is ticked (default).

Tested in Pycharm CE 2019.2.3, Ubuntu 19.04.